# If you take 2 numbers and grow them both by the same percentage, will the difference between the 2 numbers always be the same percentage as well?

Tags: number-theory

For example:

The difference between 10 and 11.80 is 18%.  If you add 3% to each number, you will get 10.30 and 12.15 and the difference between them is still 18%.  Will this ring true for any 2 numbers when you grow them both by the same percentage over time?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the quantities are $\;x,y\;$. Add $\;100\cdot r\%\;$ to each and get the numbers:

$$x+rx\;,\;\;y+ry$$

The ratio (percentage) now is

$$\frac{y+ry}{x+rx}=\frac yx\;\;\text{the same as originally}$$

Comment: Hmmm...I must have done something weird since it came as a new answer instead of editing the old one. Oh, well...

Answer (score 1):

Take any two numbers $x$ and $y$. Without loss of generality, you can say that $x<y$. Now, as you defined it, the difference between them is $\frac{y-x}{x} \cdot 100$ percent.

Now grow the two numbers by $p$ percent. This means that the new numbers will be 
$$\tilde x = x\cdot \left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right)$$
and
$$\tilde y = y\cdot \left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right).$$
I will mark $P=1+\frac{p}{100}$

Now the difference between them is 
$$\frac{\tilde y-\tilde x}{\tilde x}\cdot 100 = \frac{x\cdot P-y\cdot P}{x\cdot P}\cdot 100 = \frac{P\cdot (x-y)}{P\cdot x}\cdot 100 = \frac{x-y}{x}\cdot 100$$

Which is the difference between $x$ and $y$. The answer, therefore, is YES.

Answer (score 0):

let $a=b*x$. Then $ak=(xb)k=x(bk)$

So the proportion between the two is mantained.